# Alternative way to send data with spaces to PHP via URL Parameters

Tags: php, android

I am trying to make an android application with register page. While saving these details I am using PHP and Mysql. I am sending user data via url parameters,its all working fine for single words but in a name if there are two words, the url is breaking and data is not sent to php. How do I resolve it?

```
 class send extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://bacteriological-bus.000webhostapp.com/insert.php?name="+name+"&pass="+pwd+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&otp="+"0");

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Encoding worked for me.

```
    String url_s = "https://urweb.com/insert.php?name="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(url_s);
```

Answer (score 1):

To this kind of problems best solution is using URLEncoder
Here is an example
URLEncoder.encode(QueryString, "UTF-8")

Comment: I tried that but I am getting error.String url_s = "https://bacteriological-bus.000webhostapp.com/insert.php?name="+name+"&pass="+pwd+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&otp="+"0";
                String url_e = URLEncoder.encode(url_s,"UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL(url_e);

Comment: Don't use the full url, just use the query strings. Here is detailed example on what you need http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encode-url-parameters.html

Comment: To solve your problem quickly, just below try{ add this line String name = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");

Answer (score -1):

2 solutions are coming to mind

1. When posting data from android you should join space seperated words with a underscore or some thing like that, and in your PHP code when getting that data just split it by a underscore or whatever you used to join data
2. Modify your Php url and type a regex pattern for it , in which you url paramters can have spaces for ex parameter can be equal to a regex like `([\w\d\s]+)`

hope it works :)